# Cannot create property 'label' on string

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, user-interface, frontend

good afternoon guys, I'm getting this error of "Cannot create property 'label' on string"
I've tried several solutions but none answer my problem, if anyone knows I'd appreciate it!

HTML

```html
<po-select
    name="select"
    p-label="PO Select"
    [p-options]="empresas"
    p-field-value="fieldValue"
    p-field-label="fieldLabel"
>
</po-select>

<form #fOption="ngForm">
    <div class="po-row">
        <po-select
            class="po-md-6"
            p-label="p-field-label"
            [p-options]="labels"
            [(ngModel)]="fieldLabel"
        >
        </po-select>

        <po-select
            class="po-md-6"
            p-label="p-field-value"
            [p-options]="values"
            [(ngModel)]="fieldValue"
        >
        </po-select>
    </div>
</form>
```

```
empresas: Array<any> = [
    {
      codigo: 1,
      nomeFantasia: "TOTVS SA",
      razaoSocial: "TOTVS LTDA ",
      label: "Company TOTVS SA",
      cnpj: "01.234.567/0000-01",
      value: "0",
      id: 1,
      email: "jhon@teste.com"
    },
    {
      codigo: 2,
      nomeFantasia: "TOTVS SA",
      razaoSocial: "TOTVS LTDA ",
      label: "Company TOTVS SA",
      cnpj: "02.345.678/0000-01",
      value: "20",
      id: 2,
      email: "vick@teste.com"
    },
    {
      codigo: 3,
      nomeFantasia: "TOTVS SA",
      razaoSocial: "TOTVS LTDA ",
      label: "Company TOTVS SA",
      cnpj: "03.456.789/0000-01",
      value: "30",
      id: 3,
      email: "watson@teste.com"
    },

  ]

  labels: Array<string> = [
    'nomeFantasia',
    'label',
    'razaoSocial',
    'email'
  ]

  values: Array<string> = [
   'codigo',
   'cnpj',
   'value',
   'id'  
  ]
  
  fieldLabel = 'nomeFantasia';
  fieldValue = 'codigo';

@Input('p-options') set options(options: Array<PoSelectOption | any>) {
    if (this.fieldLabel && this.fieldValue) {
      options.map(option => {
        option.label = option[this.fieldLabel];
        option.value = option[this.fieldValue];
      })
    }
    this._options = options;
    removeDuplicatedOptions(this._options);
    removeUndefinedAndNullOptions(this._options); 
    this.onUpdateOptions();
}
```

Comment: do you see the line where you create the property `label`? Have you considered the possibility that you might be doing it on a string? where do you want to create it?

Comment: it seems that the options array holds strings and not objects